# PHP file uploaded showing false

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have a form that has multiple file uploads and each input is uniquely named, however, when attempting to get the uploaded file, my test if showing false.

Please find the code below. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

```
<label class="label" for="uploadfile">Contract:</label>
<input name="'.$ICP.'_uploadedfile" id="'.$ICP.'_uploadedfile" type="file" />
```

The $ICP var is looped out, as there can be multiple instances, so this way each name is unique and on the server side, the POST is requested for each loop of the ICP.

```
while($icp_details = mysqli_fetch_array($ICP_exist_qry)){
     $ICP_ID = stripslashes($icp_details['ICP_ID']);
     if(!file_exists($_FILES[$ICP_ID."_uploadedfile"]['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$ICP_ID."_uploadedfile"]['tmp_name'])) {
             echo false;
     } else {
             echo true;
     }
}
```

I am not having any problems retrieving the values of the other posted inputs, just the files uploaded part.

Any help on this one is appreciated. :)

Note: Form is being submitted by Ajax.

Comment: Did you try just dumping `$_FILES[$ICP_ID."_uploadedfile"]['tmp_name']` to see what you've got

Comment: Ensure your form has the following attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Tried a move_uploaded_file it fails.
Form is being submitted with Ajax, added just incase but no difference

Comment: How are you getting the form data using Javascript? i.e are you using JQuery `.serialize()` or the `FormData` object?

Comment: @GeorgeQ formData = $(this).serializeArray();

Comment: Aaaand that's the issue, files are special and can't be serialized or proccessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload the file correctly using Ajax (and in this case JQuery) you need to use the FormData object. The code snippet below illustrates how it can be used. It is used instead of the .serialize() or .serializeArray() methods.

```
$('#file-form').submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```